# element.value method is returning undefined

Tags: html, ajax

I have an ajax `'POST'` method that sends the `id` input to a php file. For some reason whenever I write `input.value` method, it returns undefined:

```
input = document.getElementsByClassName("Input");
const id = input.value;
alert(id);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I tried making the element as a separate id instead of a class and the problem disappeared.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide more context but try if this is working for you
`document.getElementsByClassName("Input")[0]` since getElementsByClassName normally returns an array.

Comment: Duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName()` returns an array-like collection of elements, not a single element.

You'll need to extract one of the elements from the collection, e.g.

```
input = document.getElementsByClassName("Input");
const id = input[0].value; //<--
alert(id);
```

Better would be to target the exact element in some way e.g.

```
document.querySelector('#theActualElement'); //<-- returns single element
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. For some reason I am getting an empty string instead of a value inputted :\

Comment: Well then something outside the scope of the question is responsible. Either you do not have elements with class `.Input` or they are not being found (you may be running this code before the elements are present in the DOM). Try to set up a [minimal, verifiable, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried making the element as a separate id instead of a class and the problem disappeared.